# If condition giving wrong output

Tags: java, android

When running this code, it always go through the `if` block.
It doesn't matter if `count` is `0`or not, it always execute this block.

```
if (!count.equals("0")) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No data in there.Count = "+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Count = "+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Fragment fragment = new PGSubCatFragment();
    Bundle bCatID = new Bundle();
    bCatID.putString("catid", cID);
    fragment.setArguments(bCatID);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
}
```

Could you explain what is wrong?

Here is the console output of my application:

```
D/PGCatFragment: Count = 0 gallery
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x579da7c0, size:0x40200, fd:64
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x574508c0, size:0xcc30, fd:69
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x549341d8, size:0x40200, fd:67
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x579dc708, size:0x40200, fd:80
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x579ea370, size:0x40200, fd:82
D/PGSubCatFragment: {"message":"No gallery found","success":0}
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x579da7c0, size:0x40200, fd:64
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x549341d8, size:0x40200, fd:67
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x579dc708, size:0x40200, fd:80
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x579ea370, size:0x40200, fd:82
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x574508c0, size:0xcc30, fd:69
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x579ffea0, size:0x40200, fd:62
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x57a002d8, size:0x40200, fd:73
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x5225ce28, size:0x40200, fd:70
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x57a00a60, size:0x40200, fd:72
D/PGCatFragment: {"success":1,"imgCat":[{"catimg":"http:\/\/live.jmpcbuiltline.com\/admin\/upload\/gallery\/430912.JPG","catid":"1","subcatcount":"5","catname":"Event"},{"catimg":"","catid":"2","subcatcount":"0","catname":"Media"}]}
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x579ffea0, size:0x40200, fd:62
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x57a002d8, size:0x40200, fd:73
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x5225ce28, size:0x40200, fd:70
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x57a00a60, size:0x40200, fd:72
D/PGCatFragment: Count = 5 gallery
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x579f5710, size:0x40200, fd:64
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x57b4dc88, size:0xcc30, fd:68
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x50685a30, size:0x40200, fd:73
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x54f8bee8, size:0x40200, fd:80
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_register_buffer, handle:0x579f55f8, size:0x40200, fd:82
D/PGSubCatFragment: {"success":1,"imgSubCat":[{"gname":"1st Event","gid":"1","catimgcount":"11","subcatimg":"http:\/\/live.jmpcbuiltline.com\/admin\/upload\/gallery\/237156.png"},{"gname":"2nd Event","gid":"2","catimgcount":"14","subcatimg":"http:\/\/live.jmpcbuiltline.com\/admin\/upload\/gallery\/4425910.JPG"},{"gname":"3rd Event","gid":"3","catimgcount":"11","subcatimg":"http:\/\/live.jmpcbuiltline.com\/admin\/upload\/gallery\/731556.JPG"},{"gname":"4th Event","gid":"4","catimgcount":"13","subcatimg":"http:\/\/live.jmpcbuiltline.com\/admin\/upload\/gallery\/967434.JPG"},{"gname":"Organise by JMPC","gid":"5","catimgcount":"15","subcatimg":"http:\/\/live.jmpcbuiltline.com\/admin\/upload\/gallery\/5253910.JPG"}]}
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x579f5710, size:0x40200, fd:64
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x50685a30, size:0x40200, fd:73
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x54f8bee8, size:0x40200, fd:80
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x579f55f8, size:0x40200, fd:82
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6613K, 24% free 22864K/29756K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
I/gralloc.sc8830: gralloc_unregister_buffer, handle:0x57b4dc88, size:0xcc30, fd:68
```

Comment: What is count? integer?

Comment: "_There is one variable that does not have the value I expect, but I'm not going to show you where that variable came from_" How exactly are we supposed to debug that?

Comment: count is string and it gives value too, but it always going to if block even condition is true or false, I checked them out by toasts my self

Comment: `Count = 0 gallery`, `Count = 5 gallery`. Your `count` variable is not `"0"`, it's `"0 gallery"`

Comment: @jhamon, please add you answer, it is too obvious ;)

Comment: We can't see the Toast statements, so it's quite difficult to help you.  Please use `Log` instead of `Toast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your logs:

```
Count = 0 gallery
Count = 5 gallery
```

`count`is not `"0"` but is `"0 gallery`

Solutions would be either:

- get the value before you add the `" gallery"` part
- use `if(!count.startWith("0 ")){` without omitting the space after the 0, in case there is digit like 05, 06. But that would not work with multiple 0s.
- use a regex `if(!count.matches("0+ gallery")){`. The `+` means 1 or more 0s
- split `count` on space character and compare the first returned string (a bit similar to the first option)

Answer (score 0):

**If `count` is String**

then Use this `if(!count.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))` instead of `if(!count.equals("0"))`

**If `count` is int**

then Use this `if(count != 0))` instead of `if(!count.equals("0"))`

Comment: If `count` were an int primitive, then you couldn't use `equals`